# A real number is rational $\iff$ its continued fraction expansion is finite.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I know that if this expansion is finite, then I can go to the lowest denominator in the whole fraction and turn it into a fraction and keep doing so until I get a fraction which means the number is rational. But how do I prove the opposite? What I thought of, is that if it is rational, then I can use the process to make it a continued fraction which is finite, I believe. But it doesn't seem like a proof to me. I would really appreciate your assessment.

Comment: Induction on the maximum (absolute) value of the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: I shall try. Isn't it complex? Both the numerator and denominator will be integers about which I have an assumption.

Comment: If you start with $m/n$, and apply the division algorithm to find $q, r, 0\le r< n$ such that $m=qn+r$, then (assuming $r>0$ for otherwise you're done)
$$
\frac mn=q+\frac rn=q+\frac1{\frac nr}.
$$ What can you say about $n/r$?

Comment: This is a bit difficult for me. Is it, after all, a two-dimensional induction?

Comment: $n\over r$ is a fraction but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Unless you originall had $|m|<n$, you now have $r<|m|$, so the numbers are becoming smaller. If you had $q=0,m>0$, then you start with $m/n=1/(n/m)$ and proceed from there as in the earlier case. It is a one-dimensional induction on either $\max\{|m|,|n|\}$ or $|m|+|n|$. The absolute value signs are ever needed in case your rational was negative to begin with, and even then only in the first step.

Comment: See [Continued Fractions and the Euclidean Algorithm](http://www.albany.edu/~hammond/gellmu/examples/confrac.pdf) for instance. And also http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheEuclideanAlgorithmAndSimpleContinuedFractions/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

---

Now conversely suppose that continued fraction is finite then we'll show that number is rational.

[image]

Comment: Here the source for anyone wondering: http://archives.math.utk.edu/articles/atuyl/confrac/intro.html